# How can I get binary file permissions from command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

By using `stat -c "%a %n" *`  I'm getting file permissions in octal mode (such as 755), Is there any way to see the file permissions in binary mode (such as 111 101 101)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a single file:

```
stat -c "%a" filename.txt | xargs -I PERM echo "obase=2; ibase=8; PERM" | bc
```

And as a more clear script for more that of one file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
  perm=$(stat -c "%a" "$file")
  bin=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=8; $perm" | bc)
  echo "$bin $file"
done
```

the output:

```
110110100 baz
110110100 foo
110110101 bar
```

---

#### Notes

- First we loop into all files and directories using `for file in *`.
- With `stat -c "%a` we gather the file permission in octal, then
- Using `echo` we add other necessary details to `permission` and pip it to `bc`.
- Finally `bc` does the conversion and then we printout the result and file name.
- obase=2; means output should be in binary, ibase=8 means our input is in octal and $perm is the file permission in octal like 664.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the perl [stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) module e.g. given

```
$ stat -c '%a %n' *
600 other file
775 somedir
664 somefile
```

then

```
$ perl -MFile::stat -e 'printf "%b %s\n", (stat $_)->[2] & 07777, $_ for @ARGV' *
110000000 other file
111111101 somedir
110110100 somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *visualize* file permissions in binary, you could use the first column of `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -ld /bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mai 18 05:38 /bin
```

Here you can see that `rwxr-xr-x` corresponds to `111101101`

Answer (score 0):

#### Python

```
$ python -c 'import sys,os;[ sys.stdout.write( " ".join([bin(os.stat( i ).st_mode)[-9:],i,"\n"]) ) for i in sys.argv[1:] ]' /etc/passwd
110100100 /etc/passwd
```

The job is done via `os.stat()` function, which returns a tuple of file attributes, among which is`st_mode` in decimal format. We then convert it to binary, and extract last 9 digits.

Everything is performed within list comprehension to operate on all files given on command-line (so you can provide multiple files or use globstar).

**As a script**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys, os

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    perms = os.stat(filename).st_mode
    print bin(perms)[-9:], filename
```

Comment: Why do you use `sys.stdout.write(' '.join([..., '\n']))` instead of just `print(...)` ?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm thinking of Python3

Comment: @wjandrea `print` doesn't work within list comprehension, at least not in Python 2.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier to read as a script. Could I add to your answer?

Comment: @wjandrea  Sure, feel free to do so.  I was considering adding that as script as well.